# Is there any usage difference between "in" and "of" in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions

I got a bachelor **of** engineering **in** Mechanical engineering.
I got a bachelor **in** engineering **in** Mechanical engineering.
I got a bachelor **of** engineering **of** Mechanical engineering.
I got a bachelor **in** engineering **of** Mechanical engineering.

Above 4 sentences seems the same to me. Are there any differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Academic institutions normally prescribe the form for an academic award. The usual form is:

> I got a bachelor of engineering in Mechanical engineering.

However, it is also  customary to capitalize the significant words in an academic award:

> I got a Bachelor of Engineering in Mechanical Engineering.

Also, "got" is very informal. There are preferred ways of expressing the idea:

> I have received a Bachelor of Engineering in Mechanical Engineering.
>   I have been awarded a Bachelor of Engineering in Mechanical Engineering.

One might use these forms in informal speech:

> I got a bachelor in engineering in Mechanical engineering.
>   I got a bachelor of engineering of Mechanical engineering.
>   I got a bachelor in engineering of Mechanical engineering

but probably not in writing, unless one is trying to demonstrate informal speech.